# Creacion de un workspace en angular

Tags: json, nodejs, angular

Estoy creando mi workspace en angular pero al finalizar me sale este error:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...rma-coverage-istanbul'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\arace\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-13T15_28_22_697Z-debug.log
>   Package install failed, see above.

Yo nueva en este tema, ya con unos tutoriales había creado otros workspace sin problema, pero hoy sale ese error y no se que hacer, desinstale node y angular, los volví a instalar y persiste el error.

Ademas al mirar la carpeta solo salen 13 elementos faltan:

1. La carpeta de `node_modules`
2. el archivo `package-lock.json`

Comment: Estás con un proxy o algo que pueda complicar la conexión a internet? A veces pasa eso cuando npm no puede conectarse.

Comment: Como lo estas generando? Que versión de `cli` usas? `node_modules` es donde esta todo lo necesario para que funcione. Tienes permisos de escritura donde generas tu proyecto?

Comment: No, no estoy con proxy.

Comment: Si tengo los permisos necesarios ya que estoy usando mi pc .